# SocialNetwork URL in text?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using SocialNetwork's SLComposeViewController to post shares about real estate properties. The share consists of a short string and an URL pointing to that property's listing on a real estate website.

I would like to add another URL, *inside* the short string. That URL would point to our app's page on the AppStore. That way the user could tap the property URL to see the property, or the app URL to see the app.

If this was going to work it would likely be via attributedString, but my attempts to get this to work have failed. Has anyone succeeded in this?

Comment: what methodology are you using? SLComposeViewController or UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Good point, SLComposeViewController and I have added that to the question.